# Insert a comma after every second character without appending a comma at the end of the string

Tags: php, string, insertion, delimited

I have this:

```
$following_user_id .= $row['following_user_id'];
```

and I get:

```
44443344330
```

then I separate with commas:

```
44,44,33,44,33,0,
```

but I don't want the last comma on the last number.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you using implode. Show the code.

Comment: Are you sure you are using implode on that one?

Comment: That usually happens when there is an empty string at the end of the array that is being imploded.

Answer (score 1):

Check implode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Code example:  I'm assuming your using some sort of loop?

```
$arrUsers = new array();

... your loop code here ...
array_push($arrUsers, $row['following_user_id']);
... end loop code .. 
$following_user_id = impload(",", $arrUsers);
```

Comment: I have already but I don't undersand, that's why I posted this, I just can't do it with a variable.

Comment: array_push($arrUsers, $row['following_user_id']);  /* and then use implode after they are all loaded in the array with */ $following_user_id = impload(",", $arrUsers);  is an example using the answer Roland gave

Comment: Roland pointed you to the link, I just added a code example that uses the information from that link.

Answer (score 1):

```
$following_user_ids = array();

//loop this:
$following_user_ids[] = $row['following_user_id'];

$user_ids_string = implode(',',$following_user_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into an array of characters, then implode the array.

```
$array = preg_split('//', $following_user_id, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

echo implode( ',', $array );
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect your data into an array of strings and use the implode function:

```
$uids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($uids, $row['following_user_id']);
}
$following_user_id = implode(',', $uids);
```

Comment: you can also do something like: $following_user_id .= ',' . $row['following_user_id']; and then just strip the comma at the beginning.

Comment: that is true, but a user should be spanked for doing it that way, when implode exists and is cleaner and not a hack.  But you are right, that would be another option. rtrim($following_user_id, ",")

Answer (score 0):

Implode should not be inserting a comma at the end of that string there.  Are you sure there isn't an empty string at the end of your array sequence?

Either way, to fix the string you have, just get rid of the last character of the string:

```
$concatUserIds = "44,44,33,44,33,0,";
$concatUserIds = substr($concatUserIds, 0, strlen($concatUserIds) - 1);
```

Further, if you're not going to be using the non-comma delimited number set, why don't you just add a comma every time you add a user id.  That way you don't even have to use the implode function.

Comment: well can you rewrite the code for me? Can you implode these with a comma?

Comment: as the outcome is 44443344330

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$following_user_id.= $row['following_user_id'];
$following_user_id=preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=(\d)+(?!\d))/',',',$following_user_id);
echo $following_user_id."<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()` to insert a comma after every two characters. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tV1CN))

```
$input = '44443344330';
echo preg_replace('/..\K/', ',', $input);
// 44,44,33,44,33,0
```

If in other circumstances, your input string has an even number of characters and you still don't want the trailing comma, then use `/..\K(?!$)/` which uses a negated lookahead for the end of the string.

---

Or without regex, you can use `word_wrap()`. The `true` 4th parameter is necessary to force the function to "break long words". ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ALAKM))

```
$input = '44443344330';

echo wordwrap($input, 2, ',', true);
// 44,44,33,44,33,0
```

This approach will not add the trailing comma even if the string has an even number of characters.

---

<sub>`chunk_split()` is not suitable for this task because it will append the unwanted comma at the end of the string.
 `echo chunk_split($input, 2, ',');` outputs: `44,44,33,44,33,0,`</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Try using arrays, example

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr[] = 'foo';
$arr[] = 'bar';
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Comment: `implode()` is only part of the answer. The asker also needs to know how to convert the string into an array.