# How do I place a comma between each character in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [seperate with commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878073/seperate-with-commas)

```
$following_user_id .= $row['following_user_id'];
```

leads to

```
44443344330
```

can you seperate each with comma, but I don't want a comma on the last one, if anyone could do this for me I would apreciate it very much